# Can Kofax client connect to different servers?

Tags: client-server, kofax

We have Kofax Capture 9 setup in 2 different departments, on the same network. One of the departments is planning on helping the other with a project. Is it possible for one department's Kofax scan stations to connect to the other departments Kofax server to provide help with scanning and validation? Can it be done in a way that will allow them to easily switch between servers?

Answer (score 5):

If i understand your problem correctly, your KC server setup is like this :

KC Server 1 (Department 1)

- Client 1(Department 1)
- Client 2(Department 1)
- Client 3(Department 1)

KC Server 2 (Department 2)

- Client 1(Department 2)
- Client 2(Department 2)
- Client 3(Department 2)

Now, you want the Client's of KC Server 1 to become the clients of KC Server 2.
If this is the Case, it can be done by editing the "**ServerPath**" registry key @:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Kofax Image Products\Ascent Capture\3.0
```

Open the Registry Editor on each of the clients of KC Server 1 and change the "**ServerPath**" keys value to **CaptureSV path** of KC Server 2 and then restart the kofax Capture services. JOB DONE !!

To again move the clients back to the KC Server 1, repeat the same step and set the CaptureSV path of KC Server 1.

Comment: Thanks. @stephen mentions an interesting license issue that would be a drawback to this solution.

Comment: No drawback - we used the solution described here without issue.

Comment: On 32-bit Kofax clients, the registry key will be: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Kofax Image Products\Ascent Capture\3.0 and of course the same value name of ServerPath value name.

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect the clients to a different license server as well :

32-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Kofax\SALicClient\`

64-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Kofax\SALicClient\`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACDeployUtil to change the ServerPath with the following command:

> ACDeployUtil /ServerPath:"\\Machine Name\CaptureSV"

Run the ACDeployUtil to know the current configuration of the client/server.

Answer (score -1):

Though it is essentially true that you can change the ServerPath key to redirect a client, it isn't officially supported to do this.  The problem you will run into is with licensing.  If you direct the client to an environment that has higher scan volume remaining then the volume will be reduced to the last value known by the client.

Depending on how similar your volume counts are, this might not be immediately noticeable, but if you go back and forth it will keep lowering both licenses to the lowest number it has seen.  The only way to resolve this will be to reset the license by working with both sales and tech support.

The only way to avoid this situation is if you actually have a single license server used by both environments.  Of course this depends on whether you actually have a single license or multiple.

Comment: Sorry, but I must disagree here: we have used this exact scenario, e.g. where "Dev" is one set of servers and "Prod" is another set; (never mind "Test" and "Qual" being two more sets - each environment with its own Kofax license)... for us, flipping a client from one environment to another had no impact at all on the volume licenses available in that environment.

Comment: That has been our experience as well, that switching a Windows PC between environments does not seem to lower license numbers in the manner described.  It's possible there could be a window of time where it behaves this way until the station's license is released by the no-longer-pointed-to server, but that should only last a few minutes at most.. I wrote a Windows WPF utility app for Kofax 10.1 client PC diagnostics that includes this functionality to switch environments by changing the registry key as @Maverick shows.  We have separate Dev, QA, and Prod installations of Kofax 10.1.

Comment: I would suggest that anyone wanting to do this open a case with Kofax technical support to confirm whether it is a supported scenario or whether there are any problems expected.  I work for Kofax TS, but have not been on the Kofax Capture team for a while, thus the possibility this behavior may have changed.  It certainly happened in past versions.